# Value of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to Integer

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am new to EF Linq and I have been struggling with this query for a few days. From reading this forum, I have managed to get this far:

```
Dim noPic = (From f In myEntities.FriendLists
             Where (f.UserID = Profile.ID)
             Select f.FriendID).Except(From g In myEntities.GuestLists
                                         Where g.EventID = _id
                                         Select g.FriendID)
Dim myNoPic As Integer = noPic
Dim show = From s In myEntities.UserProfiles
           Where s.UserID = myNoPic
           Select s.UserID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.ImUrl
Repeater2.DataSource = show
Repeater2.DataBind()
```

I am trying to get everybody from the FriendList who is not already on the GuestList to display in a Repeater control. After reading the forum I was able to append .First() to noPic at the myNoPic declaration and finally get a result but that only gave me the first element. Does anybody have any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`noPic` is a *query*. It's not an integer - it's a *sequence* of integers. So you can't convert it to a single integer, and it sounds like you don't want it to.

My guess is that you want:

```
Dim show = From s In myEntities.UserProfiles
           Where noPic.Contains(s.UserID)
           Select s.UserID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.ImUrl
```

Alternatively, write the whole thing as a join to start with. (I'm not au fait with VB LINQ syntax, otherwise I'd do that for you.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem boils down to these lines:

```
Dim myNoPic As Integer = noPic
```

and

```
Where s.UserID = myNoPic
```

What I think you are trying to accomplish is something like this:

```
Dim noPic = (From f In myEntities.FriendLists
         Where (f.UserID = Profile.ID)
         Select f.FriendID).Except(From g In myEntities.GuestLists
                                     Where g.EventID = _id
                                     Select g.FriendID)
Dim myNoPic As Integer = noPic
Dim show = From s In myEntities.UserProfiles
       Where noPic.Contains(s.UserID)
       Select s.UserID, s.FirstName, s.LastName, s.ImUrl
```

`Contains` is what we wanted. It changes your second query to "Get me all UserProfiles where their ID is in noPic".